# How to avoid the `this` and `new` keywords in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jslint

Here is my code: I want to avoid using `this` (line 3) and `new` (line 23). I want to do this because Douglas Crockford considers them harmful.

```
"use strict";
function capWord(inStr) {
   this.firstIndex = function(inStr) {
   document.write(capWord.upper(inStr[0])); 
   capWord.space(inStr); 
   };

   capWord.space = function(inStr) {
      for(var i=1;i<inStr.length;i=i+1) { 
         document.write(inStr[i]);
         if (inStr[i] == " ") {
            document.write(capWord.upper(inStr[i+1]));
            i = i+1;
          }
       }
   };

   capWord.upper = function(charUpper) {
      return charUpper.toUpperCase();
   }
}

var insCapWord = new capWord();
insCapWord.firstIndex("learning cool stuff");
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Have you tried to do it yourself?

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid `this` and `new`?

Comment: JsLint is probably bitching about it, but then it bitches about almost everything ...

Comment: I've never used JsLint but I must say I was not impressed that it couldn't parse valid, commonly-used syntax: "Unexpected 'for'" on the code `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}` What?

Comment: @Pointy I have changed my post to make it more clear.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Yes. That is a warning I am trying to find a fix for.

Comment: It's possible to rewrite the code so that it passes jslint, even with the `new` keyword (that is done by using `CapWord` instead of `capWord`), but that doesn't make it very good code. Douglas Crockford has some good points about the language, but the `jslint` tool only enforces some specific rules, it doesn't make any analysis of the code quality. For example, it doesn't catch that the constructor function attaches functions to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a constructor function you need to use `new` to create the object. You can create an object in the function and return it instead.

(Note though that this is an "anonymous" object, not an instance of `capWord`.)

Assigning functions as properties to the function itself doesn't make much sense. If you only use them inside the function you can just make them regular functions declared locally inside the function.

```
"use strict";

function capWord(inStr) {
    return {
        firstIndex: function (inStr) {
            document.write(upper(inStr[0]));
            space(inStr);
        }
    };

    function space(inStr) {
        for (var i = 1; i < inStr.length; i = i + 1) {
            document.write(inStr[i]);
            if (inStr[i] == " ") {
                document.write(upper(inStr[i + 1]));
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    function upper(charUpper) {
        return charUpper.toUpperCase();
    }
}

var insCapWord = capWord();
insCapWord.firstIndex("learning cool stuff");
```

As your original code was something that was halfway implemented as a class, I would like to show how it could look implemented fully as a class:

```
"use strict";

function CapWord(inStr) {
    this.str = inStr;
}

CapWord.prototype = {
    firstIndex: function() {
        document.write(this.upper(this.str[0]));
        this.space();
    },
    space: function() {
        for (var i = 1; i < this.str.length; i = i + 1) {
            document.write(this.str[i]);
            if (this.str[i] == " ") {
                document.write(this.upper(this.str[i + 1]));
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
    },
    upper: function(charUpper) {
        return charUpper.toUpperCase();
    }
};

var insCapWord = new CapWord("learning cool stuff");
insCapWord.firstIndex();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you did not add a semicolon after this function? `function upper(charUpper) {
        return charUpper.toUpperCase();
    }`

Comment: @user3421311: Yes, it's because there is no reason to put one there. There shouldn't be one after the `space` function either, I fixed that. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me why there is a need of a semicolon after firstIndex object?

Comment: @user3421311: That's because it's a statement: `return { ... };`.

Comment: Probably worth JSLinting *this* code. ;^) I put up a version that lints [here](http://paste.ee/p/xomGz). Biggest error caught? You have capital `CapWord` in the declaration, but add a function to camel-case `capWord`'s prototype.

Comment: @ruffin: That's the only error that I found (fixed). Everything else is just recommendations. For example putting a space between `function` and `(` is only a style choise, not anything that makes the code better.

Comment: Sure, "biggest error" was too strong; I couldn't remember if there were others. Apologies. But it did find *a really important*, mission critical one, and that's why I like linting. (Note that I'd already added `white:true` in that paste.ee. I'm not sold on the one space rule myself, though I wouldn't argue that it makes code inherently *worse*. JSLint's directives still give me *just* enough leeway that it doesn't drive me crazy.)